# iOS: Admob testing flag

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, admob

I accidentally forgot to remove the `.testing=YES` flag from my requests when I delivered my binary. Ads still seem to be being delivered, but I'm not sure if these are a 'test category' of ads or not. Is is this a problem or is it OK because the .testDevices do not include all user UDIDs (except for mine).

Should I resubmit my binary ASAP?

Answer (score 0):

No you can goto adMob  and go to app settings for your app and turn of TestMode for all the requests. [image]

```
Test Mode
This setting controls if test mode is enabled for your site. You should only disable test mode if you accidentally release your application with test mode enabled.
```